# Website display differently with different screen size

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I am really new to web design. I am building a website for students at my school.
However, on my mac, the content is displayed at the center. But on windows, the content has more room on the right than left.

```css
  .inner
{
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 25%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
   <div class="inner">
     <h1>What are you looking for?</h1>
     <br>
     <button class="button button4"><font size="6">Developer</font></button>
     <button class="button button4"><font size="6">Entrepreneur<font size="6"></button>
     <button class="button button4"><font size="6">Other<font size="6"></button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it may help you

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
        .inner-div
        {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #fafafa;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 40%;
            min-height: 200px;
        }
        .button
        {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .button:hover
        {
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
        {
            .inner-div
            {
                width: 60%;
            }
        
        
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 678px)
        {
            .inner-div
            {
                width: 90%;
            }
            .button
            {
                width: 100%;
            }
        
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner-div">
        <h1>
            What are you looking for?</h1>
        <br>
        <button class="button">
            Developer
        </button>
        <button class="button">
            Entrepreneur
        </button>
        <button class="button">
            Other
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```